# React / Hooks - Two way data binding

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'am new in react an have a problem with react-hooks and data-binding. Hook my inputs to the data-field-list is not the problem and works fine. My idea is to change, for example after a api fetch, the data-field-list and show the changed data directly in the input fields.

If i click the button [switchData] the data-list will chnage but the input values will not. How can i solve this problem?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
    
function App() {
    const config_data = {
        firstname: {label:'Firstname', value:'Ryan'},
        lastname: {label:'Lastname', value:'Johnson'},
        age: {label:'Age', value:25}
    };

    const [data, setData] = useState({
        firstname: config_data.firstname.value,
        lastname: config_data.lastname.value,
        age: config_data.age.value
    });

    const onChange_event = (e) => {
        const {id, value} = e.target;
        setData(selData => ({
            ...selData,
            [id]:value
        }));
    }

    const showData = () => {
        console.log(data);
    }

    const switchData = () => {
        setData(selData => ({
            ...selData,
            firstname: 'Michael',
            lastname: 'Swayne',
            age: 37
        }));
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <label>{config_data.firstname.label}</label>
            <input type={'text'} id={'firstname'} defaultValue={data.firstname} onChange={e => {onChange_event(e)}}></input>
            <label>{config_data.lastname.label}</label>
            <input type={'text'} id={'lastname'} defaultValue={data.lastname} onChange={e => {onChange_event(e)}}></input>
            <label>{config_data.age.label}</label>
            <input type={'number'} id={'age'} defaultValue={data.age} onChange={e => {onChange_event(e)}}></input>

            <button onClick={showData}>Show Data</button>
            <button onClick={switchData}>Switch Data</button>
            </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `value` instead of `defaultValue` on your `input`s

`defaultValue` as the name suggests, only sets the default, not any subsequent values.

e.g.

```
<input type={'text'} id={'firstname'} value={data.firstname} onChange={e => {onChange_event(e)}} />
```

and so on